# (Cloud Function web UI) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using `from googleapiclient.discovery import build` inside my Cloud Function program *(python 3.8)*.

I've been searching for help regarding an error I get when deploying my Google Cloud Function from the GCP console UI : **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'**

Some of the answers, provided by the community, to similar problems were to **update the module via pip** with : `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`. Therefore I'm **not** able to **update it or re-install it** since I'm using the **Cloud Function web UI**.

I have already added the right requirement inside the *requirements.txt* file : `google-api-python-client==1.2`

**Why am I using google-api-python-client 1.2 ?**
Because of this error message when I tried to use the latest version:
`Build failed: gclient-service-account-auth 0.2.2 has requirement google-api-python-client==1.2, but you have google-api-python-client 1.10.1`

I can't find how to solve this **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'**, do you have any clue/advice to share about this ?

Thank you in advance, can't wait to see what's your take on this issue :)

Comment: Hi, I think that it would be necessary that you use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python) in order to achieve this since is not possible install the library in CF

Comment: What are you using https://pypi.org/project/gclient-service-account-auth/ for? That project has over-constrained it's dependency on `google-api-python-client`.

Comment: google sheets api is part of google's services, it uses google's auth to get access to the sheets, thats why it needs google's auth and thats also the reason why its a part of `google-api-python-client`

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers, I'm using ```gclient-service-account-auth``` library to connect to Google Search Console API via a Service Account linked with my CF.

Comment: @MorganBouvet, I am using same scenerio as yours, i.e. GCF to connect to  drive api. I am also getting the same error. Did you get the solution?

Comment: @PratibhaGupta not at all... I'm still being stuck with this issue

Comment: @PratibhaGupta I finally managed to find a solution putting this in requirements.txt file :
`gclient-service-account-auth>=0.3.0
google-api-python-client~=1.4`

Answer (score 2):

You can add `google-api-python-client` to the requirements.txt file.